# syntax error, unexpected 'try' in PHP

Tags: php

Have error with my registration page i get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'try' (T_TRY) in /home/catchpokem/domains/catchpokemons.lt/public_html/sargcs/admin/register.php on line 18
```

My code is : `http://pastebin.com/kamBT8J3`
Really want to fix this error but i don't know how?

Comment: Paste code here

Comment: @Rishi here [link](http://pastebin.com/kamBT8J3)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once '../configs/config.php';
```

you did not put `;` after the above line taht give the error I suppose

Comment: thanks its works :)

Comment: But why i enter my data into input never data saves to mysql?

Comment: what error does it shows

Comment: It's show no error but when i watch into mysql database it shows with 0 data in

Comment: you are not fetching results in your code...you don't seem to be inserting any data on to server.Please check 

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: i'm fetching: `$row = $query->fetch();`

Comment: your query was regarding try error m not sure what you want to achieve with your code ..please explain..

Comment: i'm trying to make registration page

Comment: you will need to insert some values before fetching them...so the query you have written only returns values if there are any values in the database...so please check the link i have given above comment to see how to insert data into database using PDO..that would be helpful

Comment: i'm inserting i think `$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO nariai (vardas, ip, slaptazodis) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");`